# Select into without touching the autoincrement ID field

Tags: sql, select-into

I want to migrate data from one table to another without copying the autoincremented **ID** field.

**source_table:**

ID  LABEL

-- -----

5   text

6   text2

**dest_table:**

ID  LABEL

-- -----

```
SELECT LABEL
INTO dest_table
FROM source_table
```

Will the above statement work knowing that `ID` in **dest_table** is an auto-incremented primary key?

Comment: yes it should be fine.

Comment: @user1336827 add it as an answer not as a comment so people can vote it and I can accept it

Comment: You are almost better of creating the table and then loading it using INSERT INTO.... SELECT

Comment: Why the down votes? An explanation is required ...

Comment: If you would have pressed the F5 key you would have saved yourself a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work ans result in

1 text

2 text2

But the problem is if you have a second table that is created and will referece to the created on. Then you have to leave the values of the primary keys as they are and not ignore them.

The query is not correct:

```
INSERT INTO destination (label) SELECT label FROM source
```

Comment: But how does the query know that LABEL of source_table should fit into LABEL column of the dest_table?

Comment: By specifying the colums that you want to import

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work fine, the auto increment in the new table will just auto increment.